# T-SQL how to prevent deletion first row in table

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql

I have a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Users
(

    idUser int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
firstName varchar(40) NOT NULL,
secondName varchar(40),
lastName varchar(70) NOT NULL,
position varchar(80),
section varchar(80) NOT NULL
)
```

And someone need to delete only one of the Users. How can I prevent first row being deleted?
I can't reinsert it, first row must have idUser = 1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a Trigger on table [Users] that watch when a register from this table is being deleted. So you check if deletion is userId:1 then you don't delete it, else.. you delete it, here is the code:

```
CREATE TRIGGER sampleTrigger
    ON [Users]
    INSTEAD OF DELETE
AS
    IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM deleted WHERE idUser IN (1))
    BEGIN
        RAISERROR ('Is not allowed to delete idUser: 1',16, 1)  
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        DELETE [Users] WHERE idUser IN (SELECT idUser FROM deleted)
    END
GO
```

Comment: In Raiserror severity level 1 will not throw any error but will give an information message means it will not cause you code to jump into Catch block and code execution will continue .. it needs to be set to atleast 16 .

Comment: `deleted` can contain multiple rows.

Comment: You should use ... WHERE idUser **IN** (SELECT ... so it allows for multiple chagnes

Answer (score 0):

In this case you will need another "Audit" table which will keep records for each user in case if a user deletes a record that users details will get inserted in that table, and Create an Instead of delete trigger on User which checks in Audit table if that user details exits in Audit table then prevent it from further deletion of if does not exist in Audit table then Allow the Record Deletion and adds a row into Audit table for this user to prevent further deletions from this user.

Comment: but this will delete all the rows from this table where userid is not 1 is this what you want to do ??

Comment: `And someone need to delete only one of the Users` => Clearly not :) It's just a missing `AND` in there

Comment: @MostyMostacho well spotted dont know what she meant or trying to achieve here :S

Comment: I want to someone who use my app can delete ONLY one user if this user has different ID then 1.

Comment: In this case you will need another "Audit" table which will keep records for each user in case if a user deletes a record that users details will get inserted in that table, and Create as Instead of delete trigger on User which checks in Audit table if that user details exits in Audit table then prevent it from further deletion of if does not exist in Audit table then Allow the Record Deletion.

Answer (score -1):

You should put such logics in your Business(Logic) Layer.
check that the user to delete is no UID=1

Comment: Agreed. Hiding business logic in triggers has a nasty habit of biting you later. Proper control of who is accessing your db via a domain and api is far preferable.

Comment: @MikeParkhill - The two things aren't mutually exclusive. Putting this logic in triggers prevents against bugs in the business layer, or such logic being bypassed if the DB is accessed by some means that doesn't go through that layer.

Comment: @MartinSmith if there is a logic in one layer, other layers can, (and mostly should) overlook it. otherwise, it's seems like both the SQL Database and the Logic layer overlap.

Comment: @MikeParkhill You can't comment on the design, as you don't know what the design is! Maybe the whole system is in the database. Maybe having that user deleted would have dire consequences and so must be protected at the top level. Maybe there are compliance reasons for it to be so protected. Maybe the proper person who has control of such things has particularly fat fingers. We don't know, so to comment on the design is unwarranted and unhelpful.