# SQL Trigger prevent delete on single row

Tags: sql, triggers

I have a table where there is a row of data that I don't want anyone to deleted it.  The Table name is ProjectInProcessData.  I want to make sure the data with ID 6050 can not delete.  How can I do that?

Comment: Triggers are **highly vendor-specific** - so please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Answer (score 1):

```
    Create Trigger [dbo].[triggerPreventDeleteFormula]
         ON [dbo].[AHSC_Project_InprocessData]
    INSTEAD OF DELETE 
    AS
    BEGIN
      IF EXISTS(
    SELECT * 
    FROM deleted d
    where d.AHSC_Project_InprocessData_ID = '6610' or   d.AHSC_Project_InprocessData_ID = '6666'
    )
   BEGIN
    ROLLBACK;
    RAISERROR('Can not delete this record: this record contains default formula',16,1);
   END
   ELSE
     BEGIN
      DELETE [AHSC_Project_InprocessData]
       WHERE EXISTS (Select * from deleted d where d.AHSC_Project_InprocessData_ID = [AHSC_Project_InprocessData].AHSC_Project_InprocessData_ID)
      END
   END
```

Comment: OK - but if the `IF EXISTS` doesn't return any rows - then **you** must now do the `DELETE` operation explicitly yourself - after all, this is an `INSTEAD OF DELETE` trigger - you're running this code **instead of** running the normal `DELETE`. This code will throw an error if one of the two `ID`'s is found - and it will **DO NOTHING** in any other case - and the `DELETE` will **not happen** ...

Comment: That's all I wanted.  Those two records are the records should be prevent from users or any other developers delete them accidentally.

Comment: @user6815384
I want to understand it better. Rather than using an instead of DELETE, couldn't we just use a trigger which would be provoked on delete statement on table?

Comment: Basically I just want to prevent anyone deleting the specific two records.  I added additional code "ELSE Begin--END", then any ID besides of 6610 or 6666 then the users can delete.

Comment: @user6815384, thank you!
I was thinking of approaching the problem in the following manner. 

https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:9532331900346505711

Answer (score 0):

use where condition in times of delete

```
delete  from ProjectInProcessData  where id!=6050
```

Comment: using Trigger?  Do you have full syntaxes?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19744024/t-sql-how-to-prevent-deletion-first-row-in-table    has the answer I was looking for.